# Issue with Heroku pipeline and javascript

Tags: heroku, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-4, pipeline

I've recently deployed a Rails 4 site to Heroku and I've noticed a problem with my menu bar. I'm using Foundation so that, on small screens, the menu items on the navbar become a clickable drop-down menu. I'm also using a helper to get a gravatar, shamelessly copied from Michael Hartl's excellent Rails Tutorial book. I've noticed though, that on pages that have this gravatar the clickable menu doesn't initially work. If I refresh the page it does though. In my development environment it seems to work without refreshing the page as well, so I think that this is due to a pipeline problem. Has anyone else experienced something similar?

Comment: do you logs indicate any thing? missing or non-precompiled assets?

Comment: No they didn't but I seem to have fixed it now somehow. My CSS wasn't being compressed properly, so I changed the setting in config/environments/production.rb to true and the site now seems to load without any issues. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are some problems with turbolinks and foundation.

If you disable turbolinks, taking out from your application.js manifest

```
//= require turbolinks
```

It should be Ok for you.

If you do this you can also remove turbolinks from your gemfile.

I haven't still found a solution to get this done using turbolinks.

Hope it helps.